# MacOS App is rejected because of wrongly Dealing file system

Tags: macos, email, app-store, appstore-approval

I am writing a MailStatistics app that need to go to the file ~/Library/Mail/Envelop Index to get the mail information. My app does not write anything into the file system but when I submitted it to the Apple Store, the app gets rejected because: "Apps that do not comply with the Mac OS X File System documentation will be rejected"

Does anyone know all possible reasons that can lead to this specific rejection

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I know the problem, it may be because I set the mode to become READWRITE instead of READONLY. I changed it back and hope that Apple will accept it this time